# iPhone app using 2G, 3G, 4G network

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, ios5, 3g-network

i want to develop an application that is capable of using 2G 3G or 4G depending upon the availability of the network. Because this app will be used in different countries and there is a support of only 2G in some countries while some support 3G or 4G.. i am a little  bit confused whether my app will automatically use the Fastest network available or i will have to explicitly code for each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1695), WiFi is what is chosen first.  If that fails, then it goes to the next available (and presumably fastest) cellular network data connection.

This is the kind of thing programmers do **not** have to worry about when designing apps for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

iOS will take care of whether wifi or 3G is used. You don't need to worry about that.

If you have operations in your app that use a lot of data you may want to restrict them to when the user is on WiFi (or at least warn them). The [reachability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) shows how to do this, among other things. Worth looking into as apple have been known to reject apps that use excessive amounts of cellular data.